# Join multiple table as a return in PostgreSQL function

Tags: function, postgresql, record, return-type

I have a function written in PL/pgSQL which is mentioned here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test()
RETURNS SETOF ccdb.consumers AS
$body$

BEGIN

RETURN QUERY
SELECT consumers.* FROM ccdb.consumers JOIN ccdb.consumer_index_details USING (cin) LIMIT 10;

END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I give consumers.* in the select statement then the function executes perfectly. But when I try to get the fields also from my consumer_index_details table then I get an error saying,

```
ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
DETAIL:  Returned type character varying(30) does not match expected type numeric(13,0) in column 2.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test() line 5 at RETURN QUERY
```

Here what I understood by the error is that since in my return type I have given consumers table, it is expecting the output structure to be the same. So my question is, what should be the RETURN TYPE if I want to get the fields from multiple tables, the return could be dynamic?

Comment: Use `returns table (...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using RETURNS TABLE() with the list of columns as your table definition... 
Hope it works out for you..